# Automatically Resolve PMD Violations in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, pmd

I am trying integrating my service into existing spring cloud microservice based project where I am using `PMD` rule set defined in parent service.

But since this new service does not use the pmd rules for parent service therefore I just want to either bypass or resolve all rules in this new service which is needed to be integrated at once where I have defined violations when I am checking the pmd using command.

```
mvn pmd:check pmd:cpd-check -rf com.company.api.newservice:TestService
```

Now this `TestService` is generating pmd.xml in target folder using above command around **701 violations** is shown in this xml since priority is being set which is mandatory to be resolved else build at **jenkins will fail**. Total violation is 1442 when pmd is run normally.

I tried to use walkmod but some exceptions are coming in their dependency itself.

**GOAL:** I just need to resolve these 701 violations immediately manually it is hectic task please suggest some quick and fast fix for these prioritized violations.

Answer (score 0):

If you run inspections from IntelliJ IDE, IDE will show the inspection results window where you can [apply a quick fix](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-problems.html#apply-quick-fixes) (if exists) for the violations: You can also [load inspection results](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html#inspection-results) from IDE inspection command line tool.